# what to do after installing "ubuntu-restricted-extras" to play MP3 and MP4 files?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-restricted-extras, audio-player

I am trying to play MP3 and MP4 files, I found that I must install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package, but Rhythmbox and the video player still don't want to play musics or mp4 videos.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to play musics or mp4 videos"?

Comment: What happens when you try? Can you play them in other media player applications like Totem?

Answer (score 3):

To cover *all* of your media needs you would be best to install vlc *along with* the restricted extras package that you have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This will playback your mp3 music and mp4 videos easily...

Comment: Cause I can't access to Internet fom my computer, I downloaded it with my phone, but it shows error when Installing it , I had try vlc_2.2.2-5_i386.deb and install it with sudo dpkg -i vlc... .deb

Comment: Pointing people to an alternative player is fine, as long as you explain that you are suggesting a replacement. And it hardly ever is a solution. "Hello, My Foo Player does not play Fooz, how can I fix this?" "Try Bar player instead". That is not an answer.

Comment: @berkes Fair point but mind you the actual question asks 'what to do after installing the restricted extras' to play mp3 and mp4s and I think that 'install vlc is a fair response to that question...